# CIP Protocol : Structure and value of data in cip protocol

Tags: c++, c, protocols, dpi, libpcap

I'm parsing the CIP (Common Industrial Protocols) protocol. cip.data values ​​come in different formats.

For example:
"cip.data":"c3:00:0c:00"  or  "cip.data":"01:00"  or "cip.data":"00:c1:00"  likely

Although these values ​​appear to be hex, I could not find a value. which format and integer equivalent are they?

Comment: Have you checked the manual of whatever device whose traffic you are inspecting? It looks like that field just contains a number of hex bytes.

Comment: Yes, I checked, but I could not find anything sensible. there are places that extracts its value from decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The data payload is service dependent. A service may return respnse data consisting of the addresses data type or any complex data structure, dpending on the particular service.

The CIP data types and service response data structures are defined in the CIP Networks Library, and the binary data you observe is to be interpret according to these response data structure definitions and each data type's width and format, respecting your machine's byte ordering.